# How to call C++/C# code from NodeJS/ElectronJS to interact with a DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, node.js, dll, electron

**Use Case**

I have a DLL written in C/C++ that is the .dll file and a .h. I need to write an ElectronJS app (.exe) with NodeJS as backend to access some function calls as part of a bigger program. I also have a C# program that has implemented a basic program that uses the DLL.

**So Far**

Im able to interact with some basic functions of the DLL with [node-ffi-napi](https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/node-ffi-napi) and [ref-napi](https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/ref-napi). The main problem here is that the dll uses some really big structs (>15members of short/long/DWORD/etc) and struct pointers to obtain information. While there is [ref-struct-di](https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/ref-struct-di) it seems that it would be very hardwork to try to implement big structures and pointers to make an API wrapper on Node since is not native code.

**Options**

I think there is 3 options but since im not very familiar with Node i dont know which would be the best, what tools/packages to uses or if there is another way.

1. Hard work trying to implement my structs and structs* with [ref-struct-di](https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/ref-struct-di) and a really extensive testing to check every parameter to see if the struct is well implemented and fail proof (seg faults) since is not a native tool.
2. Use the basic implemented C# tool that already does a wrapper to the dll API and have the functions implemented. Is there a way from my Node app to have some C# code running also? So i can call the C# wrapper that has native structs and see how to convert them to a dictionary so Node use them.
3. Implement a C++ wrapper to do similar to the C# program. This way i can access the dll api (and the .h) easier to handle the calls and structs/structs* and then from Node, call some C++ functions like for example GetInformation() and return a dictionary instead of the dll original funcion.

Since the ElectronJS app will be an .exe i need to handle everything on the same program. Its possible?

To sum everything up, what would be the best way to handle the DLL? Is there a way from Node to have some C++/C# code running also and interact with the app in runtime so i can call the dll? Anyone know any tool/package/github/link to use/read more about?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Im reading about [Node-API](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html) to integrate C++ code as addon. As my understanding, i will have a C++/.h files inside my Electron app and then compile everything. So my C++ code calls the DLL and then from Node i call the C++ wrapper. Is this correct?

Another way would be to create a new DLL in C++ that calls the original DLL. Then with ffi from Node access the new DLL that returns me a json/string or something less "complex" with only the info i need and not all the big structs. Right? Ideas? this way seems easier to write two separate programs without the N-API but would require two compilations.

Comment: In a similar problem, I preferred to implement some wrappers by using napi.h. So, I tried to compile all the code again with node-gyp. You can check some examples in https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples. It was not that difficult, but the worst thing was that I had to change my compiler. My operating system is Windows and I used to compile my C++ code with gcc under MSYS2. Node.js requires having MSVC in Windows (or maybe I could not find any trick https://stackoverflow.com/q/69243382/2979477?stw=2). Fortunately, my C++ code did not come with a lot of troubles in MSVC.